# Pyspark add row based on a condition

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a below dataframe structure

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | open | 01.01.22 10:05:04 |
| 1 | In-process | 01.01.22 10:07:02 |

I need to insert a row before the open value row.So,I need to check the status whether its **open** and then add a new row before it with other columns being the same values except the C column to get 1hour subtracted. How this can be acheived using Pyspark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of "insert a row" – which is a non-trivial issue to solve –, think about it as "union dataset"

###### Assuming this is your dataset

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, 'open', '01.01.22 10:05:04'),
    (1, 'In process', '01.01.22 10:07:02'),
], ['a', 'b', 'c'])

+---+----------+-----------------+
|  a|         b|                c|
+---+----------+-----------------+
|  1|      open|01.01.22 10:05:04|
|  1|In process|01.01.22 10:07:02|
+---+----------+-----------------+
```

###### Based on your rule, we can construct another dataset like this

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df_new = (df
    .where(F.col('b') == 'open')
    .withColumn('b', F.lit('Before open'))
    .withColumn('c', F.to_timestamp('c', 'dd.MM.yy HH:mm:ss')) # convert text to date with custom date format
    .withColumn('c', F.col('c') - F.expr('interval 1 hour'))   # subtract 1 hour
    .withColumn('c', F.from_unixtime(F.unix_timestamp('c'), 'dd.MM.yy HH:mm:ss')) # revert to custom date format
)

+---+-----------+-----------------+
|  a|          b|                c|
+---+-----------+-----------------+
|  1|Before open|01.01.22 09:05:04|
+---+-----------+-----------------+
```

###### Now you just need to union them together, and sort if you want to "see" it

```py
(df
    .union(df_new)
    .orderBy('a', 'c')
    .show()
)

+---+-----------+-----------------+
|  a|          b|                c|
+---+-----------+-----------------+
|  1|Before open|01.01.22 09:05:04|
|  1|       open|01.01.22 10:05:04|
|  1| In process|01.01.22 10:07:02|
+---+-----------+-----------------+
```

Comment: You'd need to convert it to datetime type first, then you can add using interval